# Wildfly can't connect to datasource

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, wildfly, koding

I have a Wildfly 8.2.0.Final uploaded on an Ubuntu Vm on www.koding.com.
On that same VM THere's an Oracle XE 11G.
I'm trying to configure a DataSource on the VM's wildfly and I'm getting an error.
Connection URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@anlevant.koding.io:1521:XE
[wildfly VM error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57xkF.png)

But if I create a connection withthe same Connection URL on a local wildfly, it will work!

[Succes message on local wildfly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBSpg.png)

I'm wondering what am I doing wrong on the VMs wildfly.

PS: VM Wildfly's standalone is configured to listen on 0.0.0.0

Comment: What are the *details* of that error?

Comment: Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "OmeteusDS")
    ],
    "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation: JBAS010447: Connection is not valid",
    "rolled-back" => true
}

Comment: @LevantAlejandro: please check error logs of the server to get a more descriptive error detail

Comment: It ended up being a problem with the Databaseitself, the TNS Listener service wasn't up on the virtual machine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to leave the answer that worked for me here:

"It ended up being a problem with the Database itself, the TNS Listener service wasn't running on the virtual machine, thanks! "